# Conditions for $A \cap C = B \cap C$ $\Rightarrow$ $\partial A \cap C = \partial B \cap C$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $C$ be a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
What are the conditions for the following statement to hold? 
If $A \cap C = B \cap C$ then $\partial A \cap C = \partial B \cap C$.

Comment: Do you know what "$\partial{A}$" means?

Comment: $\partial A$ is defined as the boundary of the set $A$.